# Filtering With Multi-Index Pandas and Styling

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I am attempting to highlight cells based on number of recurring values (>1) using a multi-index and export to excel with the styling.  No matter which order I try, something does not get processed through completely.  Pardon the frame formatting, it's coming from an excel file, df.head() shown.

```
  Account   Title         Mrgi  Name
0   2001    Tad Philips     M   John
1   2002    Bran Rolfo      C   Brian
2   2003    Three Stuges    C   Mary
3   2004    Humity Thumblot C   John
4   2005    Three Stuges    C   John

x_multi = df.Title.value_counts()[df.Title.value_counts() > 1].keys().tolist()

def color_highlight(var):
#print(var)
    if var in x_multi:
        color = 'yellow'
    else:
        color = 'None'
    return 'background-color: {}'.format(color)

df.set_index(['Name','Title'],inplace=True)
df.style.applymap(color_highlight,subset='Title')
```

This throws an error of style not supported for non-unique indicies.  Which I understand, but can't figure a way around it...If I apply the style then set_index it removes styling.  Help Please.

Comment: Would it satisfy the 'unique-y' requirement if you also include the original number index together with 'Name' and 'Title'? ```df.set_index(['Name','Title','index'], inplace=True)```

Comment: Kerwei, that allows the formatting but throws off the index sorting as it adds another level which doesn't allow the correct set_index result as ['Name','Title']